# Get key values of a generic Dictionary <,> using reflection

Tags: c#

How can I get the key values of a generic `IDictionary<,>` using reflection.

This is the type of thing I want to do.

```
public static string Format<T>(T item)
{
    if (item.GetType().GetInterfaces().Any(x => x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IDictionary<,>)))
    {
        // I know it's a IDictionary so figure out what the types are
        Type keyType = item.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
        Type valueType = item.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[1];

        //Now cast it to the correct IDictionary.  How do I properly inject the type here?
        var keyList = ((IDictionary<keyType, valueType>)item).Select(x => x.Key.ToString()).ToArray<string>();

    }
}
```

Edit: Clarified that I want to use reflection

Comment: It is not possible.  You cannot cast to a type that you don't know at compile time.  You can call its properties and methods using reflection, or you can call them inside a generic method and then call that using reflection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating things. When I look at your code, you are trying to do the following:

```
myDictionary.Keys.Select(k => k.ToString()).ToArray();
```

So,

```
public string Format<T>(T value) {
    if (##item is dictionary) {
        var items = name.GetType().GetProperty("Keys", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).GetValue(item) as IEnumerable;
        if (items == null) throw new ArgumentException("Dictionary with no keys?");
        string[] data = items.OfType<object>().Select(o => o.ToString()).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you cannot pass a `System.Type` as a type argument. If you want to use the `IDictionary<,>` properties, you need to do a little more reflection.

```
var dictionaryType = typeof(IDictionary<,>).MakeGenericType(keyType, valueType);
var keysProperty = dictionaryType.GetProperty("Keys");
var keys = ((IEnumerable)keysProperty.GetValue(item)).OfType<object>().Select(k => k.ToString()).ToArray<string>();
```

However, if all you want are the keys, you can just use the non-generic `IDictionary` interface, and don't bother with reflection.

```
var dictionary = item as IDictionary;
if (dictionary != null)
{
    var keyList = dictionary.Select(x => x.Key.ToString()).ToArray<string>();
}
```

Comment: Your code gives me "IEnumerable does not contain a definition for select"

Comment: Oh right, linq only works on the `IEnumerable<>` interface. I''l update my answer.

Comment: you could use `(ICollection<string>) dictionary.Keys`

Answer (score 1):

You got a few problems here. One minor issue is you don't use the found interface for getting the generic arguments.

The other bigger problem is you're trying to use dynamically found types in types defined statically at compile time (`IDictionary<keyType, valueType>`).

If you want to continue down this road it's using reflection, which can be hard. Depending on your goal you could choose another path and try this out:

```
public static string Format<TKey,TValue>(IDictionary<TKey,TValue> item)
{
    var keyList = item.Select(x => x.Key.ToString()).ToArray();
    // do some work with keyList and return a string.
}
```

This will still work `public static string Format<T>(T item)` handling other types, so implementing this beside it:

```
public static string Format<T>(T item)
{
    // handle non IDictionary<,> objects here
}
```

Making you able to call format anywhere:

```
Format(new Dictionary<string,int> { { "hello world", 1337 } });
Format("string");
Format(new { Hello = "World" });
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense that it wouldn't be able to compile. Unfortunately I can't specify a dictionary parameter in the method signature because I am not specifically working with dictionaries, I just need to handle objects that inherit from IDictionary differently.  When you say "you don't use the found interface for getting the generic arguments" what do you mean?  The rest of my code is going to have to use reflection quite heavily so I am going to have to get to grips with it, what approach would you suggest?

Comment: Just extend the answer to make it a bit more clear. About the "found interface". When you lookup the IDictionary you should save the interface, like `var foundInterface = item.GetType().GetInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IDictionary<,>))` and check that its not null. If so use the `foundInterface` for getting the GenericArguments. This is important, since the type implementing the interface does not always use the same generic arguments.

Comment: I could but that wont actually make my life any easier I don't think as I need to make Expression.PropertyOrField() representation of accessing the object anyway and having a seperate function would be confusinf as it would not be obvious which one has to be used which could cause several issues I think although I will go this way if I hit wall.

Comment: I am sorry I still don't understand.  Can you give me an example of something that would have different arguments please?  Thank you for your patience.

Comment: One of main reasons I am checking for IDictionary is that I am using refecltion later on to get properties to build a lambda and it doesn't work with ExpandoObject and ExpandoObject implements IDictionary.  I should re-make question with fuller explanation of what I am trying to do I think as I was not clear.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're trying to get generic code parameters from `Type` objects. This is not *directly* possible, because `Type` is a class like nay other, it just represents a class, and type arguments are used to compile the method. Thus, you can't get new type arguments within the underlying code...

That being said, You could add extra generic parameters, with specific constraints,

```
public static Format<T, TKey, TValue>(T item)
    where T : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>
```

Or, to be more succinct

```
public static Format<TKey, TValue>(IDicitonary<TKey, TValue> item)
```

This can then be called using `dynamic` so as to ensure the proper arguments are used

```
public static string Format<T>(T item)
{
    if (item.GetType().GetInterfaces().Any(x => x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IDictionary<,>)))
    { FormatDictionary((dynamic) item); }
}

private static FormatDictionary<TKey, TValue>(IDicitonary<TKey, TValue> item)
```

If you *must* perform these calls with `Type` objects, you'll have do so via metacode - either with more reflection calls, or by compiling a method using [Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)